# create custom badness for pagebreaking over a custom area

Tags: macros, page-breaking, badness

This is a - as I think - tricky question. I want to create and/or modify a badness for pagebreaking/newpage.

It should work like this (pseudo code):

```
\begin{areaOfBadnessValid}{badnessvalue}
\pagebreakingbadness = badnessvalue
Some Text Text Text Text Text Text\\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\ifPagebreakBadness>i.e.10000
\newpage
\fi

Another Text Text Text Text Text Text\\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\\
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\end{areaOfBadnessValid}
```

Where can I get more information about badness rules and modifying them?
I want to know how this can be done, not just a solution for this special case. I already read about some `\tolerance` which might be helpfull here (i.e. decrease tolerance and add a `\pagebreak`)

Comment: The TeXbook (Computers and Typesetting #1) by Knuth.

Comment: If anyone ever reads this: The proper term for research is "penalty".